# How to add waits for click functions in generic methods?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]
I have class called `Generics`, in the class I write all the generic methods like `clickElement`, `ClickOnButton`...etc... Unlike using `thread.sleep` in actual class I want to add defaultly wait until element visible in generics class for Click elements.

I want to add waits in generic method in generic class not for implemention class.

this is genrics calss

```
public void clickElement(WebDriver driver, String xpathExpress) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpress)).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Explicit wait to create generic methods.

Example Methods for **Explicit Wait**:

```
/**
 * Wait for element to appear on the webpage
 * @param driver
 * @param locatorObject
 */
public void waitForElementToBeVisible(WebDriver driver, By locatorObject) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locatorObject));
}


/**
 * Waits for element to become interactive/clickable
 * @param driver
 * @param locatorObject
 */
public void waitForElementToBeClickable(WebDriver driver, By locatorObject) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locatorObject));
}
```

Hope this helps.